# Combine two optional into one using elegant way

Tags: java

Basically i'm trying to create this code in 1 line. Check if guild exists to delete then try create a new guild and if its not null to add to my current map.

````
Optional.ofNullable(getGuild(event.getGuild().getIdLong())).ifPresent(Guild::deleteMe);
Optional.ofNullable(Guild.create(event.getGuild().getIdLong(), event.getGuild().getName())).ifPresent(s -> addGuild(s));```
````

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the first `ifPresent` consumer in a way to handle both actions and limit the second one to a method reference

```
Optional<Guild> eventGuild = event.getGuild();

if(eventGuild.isPresent()){

    long eventGuildId = eventGuild.getLongId();
    
    Optional.ofNullable(getGuild(eventGuildId)).ifPresent(guild -> {
        guild.deleteMe();
        Guild.create(eventGuildId, eventGuild.getName()).ifPresent(this::addGuilds);
    });
}
```

I don't know if this is more elegant in your eyes, but it's definitely more readable.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Well both look better than my way for sure but still a mess. Java should have added an else if style in Optional or more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If there were no extra processing we could've used `or` funtion:

```
Optional.ofNullable("oldGuild").or(()->Optional.ofNullable("newGuild"));
```

Note: For demonstration, I am using `String` class instead of Guild.
Just to get in in one Optional we can try `flatMap`. This is not readable and may not look elegant. But we can cram all of it in one optional.
Consider it as replacing old guild with new one:

```
Optional.ofNullable("oldGuild").<String>flatMap(guild->{
        if(guild!= null) guild.length();/*delete*/
        return Optional.ofNullable("newGuild");
    }).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```